# Distinguishing Brown Ring Test for Nitrates and Nitrites

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

My question is how will one detect the presence of nitrates by brown ring test when nitrites are also present in the solution?

**Brown Ring Test for Nitrite**
$\ce{NO_2^- + H+ -> HNO2}$
$\ce{3HNO2 -> H2O + HNO3 + 2NO}$
$\ce{FeSO4 + 6H2O -> [Fe(H2O)6]SO4}$ 
$\ce{[Fe(H2O)6]SO4 + NO -> [Fe(H2O)5NO]SO4 + H2O}$

**Brown Ring Test for Nitrate**
$\ce{2NO_3^- + 6Fe^2+ +4H2SO4 -> 6Fe^3+ + 4SO4^2- + 2NO + 4H2O}$
$\ce{FeSO4 + H2O -> [Fe(H2O)6]SO4}$
$\ce{[Fe(H2O)6]SO4 + NO -> [Fe(H2O)5NO]SO4 + H2O}$

Note: I personally think that it may have something to do with preventing oxidation of nitrites to nitrates and the release of NO (nitric oxide). But I am not quite sure how to go about that.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are quite right. It has something to do with prevention of oxidation of nitrites. By controlling the pH, the nitrite present is reduced to nitric oxide ($\ce{NO}$) which reacts with ferrous sulfate to form a brown-colored complex ion, $\ce{FeSO4.NO}$. Nitrates do not react in such way and thus not registered in the test. It uses a special agent to prevent color formation or precipitation of common
interfering ions. Here is the relevant information[1]:

> The high range nitrite test is a modification of the classical brown
>   ring test for nitrate using ferrous sulfate. By controlling the sample
>   pH, the nitrite present is reduced to nitrous oxide, which reacts with
>   the indicator to form a greenish-brown color. Nitrates are not
>   registered in the test. [...]
>
> In an acidic medium ferrous sulfate reduces nitrogen in nitrite
>   ($\ce{NO2–}$) to form nitrous oxide ($\ce{NO}$). Ferrous ions combine
>   with the nitrous oxide to form a brown-colored complex ion, the color
>   intensity of which is in direct proportion to the nitrite present in
>   the water sample. Color development follows Beer’s Law.
>
> $$\ce{2Fe^2+ + 4H+ + 2NO2‾ → 2Fe^3+ + 2NO + 2H2O}$$
>
> $$\ce{NO + FeSO4 → FeSO4·NO}$$

**Reference**

1. https://www.hach.com/asset-get.download.jsa?id=7639984196